# Error al hacer git pull origin master

Tags: git, github, git-pull

En la terminal de Linux me sale error al hacer
***git pull origin master o git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histoires***
para hacer merge con con el archivo Readme que se creo al hacer el nuevo repositorio en Github.

Las ramas que hice antes se fusionaron bien, igual no hay nada para hacerle add o commit.

1. Este es el primer comando que utilizo para traer el archivo README que se creo en el repositorio de Github hacia la rama master y fusionarlos.

***`:~$ git pull origin master`***

2. Este es el segundo comando

***`:~$ git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`***

En los dos me sale el mismo mensaje:
***Fatal: Necesita especificar cómo reconciliar las ramas divergentes***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. Recuerda siempre mostrar la salida en consola o el código _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. 2. ¿Hiciste lo que indica el mensaje?

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo lo modificaré, sobre tu pregunta ese es el problema no se a que se refiere soy nuevo usando Git así que esperaba que me dijeran a que se refería el mensaje que aparece, muchas gracias.

Comment: El mensaje indica que no hay una configuración establecida para la estrategia de `pull` en tu repositorio local. Existen diferentes estrategias, debes aplicar una de ellas tal como se indica en el mensaje. Probablemente la más adecuada en tu caso sea `merge`, que es la estrategia por defecto. Sólo tienes que escribir en la consola `git config pull.rebase false` y dar Enter para aplicar la configuración. Saludos

Comment: Listo muchas gracias por su apoyo ya quedó!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!